# Imported python package unrecognized submodule

Tags: python, openstack

I am unsure why when I run the command `openstack`, I get this error below, when the openstackclient.shell submodule is supposed to come with the python-openstackclient package:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/openstack", line 5, in <module>
    from openstackclient.shell import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openstackclient.shell'
```

I followed this documentation ([Link to python-openstackclient package](https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/latest/contributor/api/modules.html)), I ran this command: `pip install python-openstackclient`

And I can confirm it is installed with `sudo pip list` in my SUSE machine with python3

Comment: According to that page, `openstackclient.shell` is a submodule.  Submodules aren't always automatically recognized; sometimes you have to explicitly import them.  Try adding `import openstackclient.shell` above the failing import.

Comment: @JohnGordon Unfortuantely it returned the same error:   File "/usr/bin/openstack", line 5, in <module>
    import openstackclient.shell
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openstackclient.shell'

Comment: Does `import openstackclient` work?  If so, what is the output of `print(openstackclient.__file__)`?

Comment: @JohnGordon The `import openstackclient` doesn't return an error. But `print(openstackclient.__file__)` will return an error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/openstack", line 6, in <module>
    print(openstackclient.__file__)
AttributeError: module 'openstackclient' has no attribute '__file__'`

Comment: Did I install the package incorrectly?

Comment: The symptom indicates that you installed the module somewhere outside your regular `PYTHONPATH` but your question doesn't contain enough details to properly troubleshoot this. Installing the module in a virtual environment here allows me to run it without issues (version 6.3.0).

Comment: Hmm.  Most modules do have a `__file__` attribute, but sometimes they don't.  Try this `print(dir(openstackclient))`

Comment: Is this a followup question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77355953 ?  If so, I think this is all a result of attempting to install the latest version of `openstackclient` into Python 2.7.  You need Python 3.8 or later.   Or you need to install an older version of `python-openstackclient` ... from before Python 2.7 support was dropped.